# Maven: maven.compiler.source, maven.compiler.target settings - which version numbers correspond to which Java Language Versions?

Tags: java, maven

For my particular install of Eclipse, with the particular Maven archetype which I am using, I find these defaults in `pom.xml`:

```
<maven.compiler.source>1.7</maven.compiler.source>
<maven.compiler.target>1.7</maven.compiler.target>
```

I don't understand what "1.7" means. What does this number correspond to? Is it the JDK version?

I thought that this should be the Java Language version, but that is clearly not correct. At the time of writing, I believe the most up to date version of "Java the Language" is Java 20, although Java 17 is the current "long term support" version.

How do I figure out the corresponding numbers for `maven.compiler.source` and `maven.compiler.target`, for each Java (language) version?

For example:

- Java 20 -> what value for `maven.compiler.source/target` ?
- Java 17 -> what value for `maven.compiler.source/target` ?

Comment: Straight from the [Oracle website](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/jdk7-naming.html). `1.7` is version 7.  From what I read, I believe Java 9+ just uses the version number. So you would want `20` or `17`.

Comment: @CalvinP. Not sure I understand how that helps as it discusses Java 7 only.

Comment: I haven’t found much of anything that explicitly says it, but through searching I’ve found several pom.xml examples using `<maven.compiler.source>17</maven.compiler.source>` and likewise for `target`. One such example for adding Java 17 support is [here](https://simply-how.com/getting-started-with-java-17) in section 3 (roughly halfway down the page), titled “Tooling support for Java 17”

Answer (score 0):

As of Java 11 (or maybe 9), the period was dropped, so yes, you want 17 or 20, respectively.

Although, you cannot set the value higher than the JDK that Maven is using (often set by `JAVA_HOME` environment variable)

Use the `javac` command to list supported versions you can use

> The supported values of release are the current Java SE release and a **limited number of previous releases, detailed in the command-line help**.

> **Note: The target release must be equal to or higher than the source release.**

You don't need to set them the same value, though. For example, you'd down-compile to JDK 1.7 / 1.8 if you were to run your code on legacy systems that don't have  an updated JRE installed